# Error: "No identities are available for signing" Xcode 4.3.1

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4, osx-lion

I upgraded my OSX from Snow Leopard to Lion and I downloaded Xcode 4.3.1
Now when I try to validate and publish my app I get the first screenshot.
If I click on Download Identifier button I get the second screenshot.

Any suggest?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Got the same problem, and this worked for me :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11230464/1474817

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The certificates you created for signing your application are only valid on the machine (+ OS) which you used to create them. They can be migrated to another machine but if you already updated without doing so, I recon that this is not an option anymore. I also don't know what the "Import Developer Profile" button does (I guess it's fairly new) but you could try that out.
If this doesn't do the trick, don't worry. Just log on your ADC account, revoke the old certificates, create new ones and modify your project accordingly. (Just like you did, when you first created them.)

Comment: Here is a reference on starting over fresh.[link] (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6)

Comment: I am facing this issue today when i upgraded Mac from 10.8 to 10.8.5 and upgraded Xcode from 4 to 5.0. I am seeing the same dialog box. I followed all your mentioned steps but still dialog box is appearing. If I click to "download Identities" then it fetch the correct certificate but then when I press Ok then XCode crashes!... Please suggest If I am missing anything , Or, few more steps are needed .... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 31):

I had this same exact error after upgrading my Xcode from 4.2.x? to 4.3.1 via the app store. I did not upgrade my OS or any hardware, and my certificates were only about 2 months old. I has submitted an app update just days before this starting happening and I feel 100% sure that something in the Xcode upgrade caused it to happen.

After a few days fiddling with it by rejecting my developer certificates and updating all the apps and provisions profiles, as well as distribution profiles. I noticed something.. See screen shot.
[image: ---]
The certificate that I was signing the app with was in the group "Identities with out Provisioning Profiles" I went back into the developer provisioning portal and downloaded the distribution certificate for my app, and added to my system, then updated the code signing identity with the correct certificate and I was able to get past this issue.
[image]

In short this message may suggest, you signed the archive with the wrong certificate. check it and make sure its the one for your app for distribution and it should work.

Happy Programing!

Comment: This solved it for me - it turns out I had never actually created a distribution profile. +1

Comment: As I have mentioned in above comment. I also verified your suggestion but still I am facing this issue. Please suggest

Comment: How do you get that screen that lists provisioning profiles without identities?

Answer (score 4):

I come to know how to resolve this problem, It is quite simple, you just need to add an additional distribution provision profile in ios developer center.

1. Log into ios developer center.
2. Enter ios Provision portal.
3. Select provision on left column.
4. Select the Distribution tab on top in details column.

I can't post the screenshot bcd because my reputation is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was missing distribution provisioning profile.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when we tried to upload an app too. We solved it in a way that I still don't understand completely, but I had an App ID that included some kind of ID in front of it like this: `XXXXXXXXXX.com.plexical.start.bask`. I put that string in my `*-Info.plist`file. After having the problem above, I switched from automatic Code Signing Identity to manual and selected the same Distribution as the automatic one. Then I got a readable error from XCode complaining that the App ID didn't match `com.plexical.start.bask`:

[image]

I proceeded to change the App ID to `com.plexical.start.bask` in the `*-Info.plist` file and after that I was able to submit the App. I still don't understand completely why, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

What happened to me was that my Distribution Provision Profile had expired. All I had to do was delete it and create/download a new Distribution Provision Profile. Xcode automatically installed it and went to the next screen.

Answer (score 2):

The validation process does not work with Ad-hoc profiles. Need to create a Distribution provisioning profile. It is not specified in the instructions for beta testing. I agonized all day until realized.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your distribution provisioning profile is out-of-date. Just open your [provisioning profiles here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action) and select one from the list, and click on Edit button from the options. After that download the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this took some fiddling and I finally got it to work.

The issue was that I created an archive and then renamed my project. This is a big no no apparently (which makes sense) which I didn't realize at the time.

I noticed that the bundle identifier in the archive was different from the one that was in the  general settings.

If this combination happens to you, simply delete the archive you created and create a new one. This will at least be your first step at cleaning up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

These steps solved it for me (some of them are in the answers above):

1. Update to Xcode 5.0.1 (current version); otherwise Xcode crashed when pressing "Cancel"
2. Update of my "Distribution iOS Provisioning Profile" in the [Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com) because mine were outdated.
3. Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Apple IDs >  > View Details:

   - The list below in the popup was outdated
     ==> Select iOS Distribution and press "+" (I don't remember what Magic happened then, however the list was actual after that)
4. As in the answer above: 
   In Xcode go to the Build Setting and search for "code signing" and:

   - Change the "Code Signing Identity" for "Distribution" and "Release" to "iPhone Distribution"
   - Change the "Provisioning Profile" for "Distribution" and "Release" to  (I could not find it before doing step 4)

I was very glad that I didn't have to revoke everything in the Developer Portal.

My announcement to Apple: Please, make this process much more easier and bugfree! It's such a hassle that costs me hours every time you force me to update to a new MacOS, Xcode, iTunes, iOS in order to keep my software running!