# No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, submit

I've asked a question related to distribution profile yesterday because it was invalid in Xcode Organizer. That problem has been solved by deleting my certificates and redownloading new certificate.
Now, I have a different problem with submit my app to App store.
I'm using Xcode4.3.2.

I think I have seen all kinds of homepage or similar question with this " No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates" error, but still I cannot find out how to solve this....

My both developtment provisioning profile and distribution provisioning profile status are valid in xcode organizer, so I select in Xcode Product -> Archive, then I get above error.

My Build Setting's Code Singning is like this;

Code Sining Identify:Mutiple values

Debug:Dont Code Sing

Any SDK:iPhone Developer iPhone Developer(for Application identifier 'myAppname')

Release:iPhone Distribution iPhone Distribution(for Application identifier 'myAppname')

Any SDK:iPhone Distribution iPhone Distribution(for Application identifier 'myAppname')

Any iOS SDK:iPhone Distribution iPhone Distribution(for Application identifier 'myAppname')

If I change the Release Any iOS SDK part to iPhone Developer form iPhone distribution, then build succeeds, but another error occurs..."No identities are available for signing" [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635939/error-no-identities-are-available-for-signing-xcode-4-3-1)

And even if I click "Download Identities", it doesn't work..

Does anyone know how to solve this problem...?
I would highly appreciate if you could tell me what to do.
I'm sorry for my bad English and illegible writings..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Problem has been solved! I had to write exactly same bundle identifier when I create my Apple IDs! How stupid am I...