# iOS No identities are available for signing

Tags: ios

I looked at a number of these issues on stackoverflow but I couldn't find one that helped me. I have what looks to be the same problem as [Error: "No identities are available for signing" Xcode 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635939/error-no-identities-are-available-for-signing-xcode-4-3-1)

If I click Download identities, it finds nothing. If I click Import Developer Profile it only allows me to select .developerprofile. If I select the 1 I have it doesn't accept it and comes back to the same screen as in the link.

When I go to iTunes Connect and make and download a profile they all end in .mobileprovision and the validating of the archive won't let me select them from my download folder (they are grayed out).

What am I missing? How do I make a .developerprofile like this seems to be only wanting?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you work carefully through this documentation https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/gettingstarted/ if you haven't already and possibly you may need to recreate your developer certificate request and start over from scratch.

Comment: Been looking at this before and now again. I'm just not understanding why I can't validate my archive :(

Comment: The link here is now bad.